# Angular ngFor not updating after data change

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have thins application in angular, in one of my components, I get some data through an `@Input() columns` from the parent component.

And I iterate it in my view with a normal `*ngFor`.

`let column of columns`

But when I change the data my `*ngFor` doesn't change. I already check the changes in the `ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)` and also I already tried to reassign the value, I used `lodash` and used the `ChangeDetectorRef`.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

constructor( private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    debugger; // this debugger does enter
    this.columns = changes.columns.currentValue; ////didn't work
    this.columns = [...this.columns]; ////didn't work
    this.columns = _.cloneDeep(this.columns); ////didn't work
    this.columns = [..._.cloneDeep(this.columns)]; ////didn't work
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); ////didn't work
}
```

Whatever I tried my view remains the same in the `*ngFor`, before it, I put a `{{colums | json}}` to see if my object it's been changed, and it is, it's just the `*ngFor` the one that is not updating.

-----------------------------Update----------------------------

I also assigned it the `changes.columns.currentValue` value and I have a debugger in the `ngOnChanges` that enters every time I change the value

Comment: how do we know ngOnChanges is being executed?

Comment: What @dalorzo said is a valid point, does it actually trigger? If not, the issue is probably in the parent where you pass the value to the input.

Comment: @Dalorzo @MikeOne it is triggered, I added i debugger in that part, and it enters, I also checked and the value it's changed, but still the `ngFor` doesn't update

Comment: need to see the relevant input code and template code. you're doing something non typical that is breaking the relation

Comment: are you using a trackBy function in your ngFor?

Comment: @tcrite no I haven't tried that

Answer (score 0):

The currentValue in the SimpleChanges holds the current snapshot of the data when its dependencies changes. Add `this.columns = changes.columns.currentValue` to the ngOnChanges.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    this.columns = changes.columns.currentValue;
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, and still the `*ngFor` doesn't update

Answer (score 0):

You can use set/get methods for change detection.

Let assume that we have an input variable named `columnID`

We can write our code like following.

**ColumnComponent:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-column',
  templateUrl: './column.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./column.component.css']
})
export class ColumnComponent {
    _columnID: string;

    set columnID(value: string) {
        this._columnID = value;
        this.propChanged();
    }
    get columnID(): string {
        return this._columnID;
    }
}
```

Your html you can use this component like this;

```
<app-column [columnID]="someVariable"></app-column>
```

When *someVariable* changes, ColumnComponent's **set columnID()** method will be called.

You can find more information for getter/setter [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter)